# bottomsheet by accompanist navigation has different behavior

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, material-design, bottom-sheet, jetpack-compose-accompanist

So, i have 2 `bottomsheet` composable named `DetailCharacter` and `Synopsis`. But this 2 composable behave differently, when i touch outside of the `bottomsheet` area, the `synopsis` close the `bottomsheet` and also popup the route from backstack, but  `DetailCharacter` is only closing it without popup the route from backstack.

Here is the code of the `Synopsis Composable`:

```
                bottomSheet(
                    route = Screen.FullSynopsisScreen.route,
                    arguments = listOf(
                        navArgument(
                            name = "mal_id"
                        ) {
                            type = NavType.IntType
                        }
                    )
                ) { navBackstack ->
                    val animeID = navBackstack.arguments?.getInt("mal_id") ?: 0
                    val viewModel = hiltViewModel<DetailAnimeViewModel>()

                    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
                        viewModel.initiateView(animeID)
                    }

                    val animeResource by viewModel.anime.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
                    Surface(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .animateContentSize()
                    ) {
                        when (animeResource) {
                            is Resource.Success -> SynopsisScreen(synopsis = (animeResource.data as Anime).synopsis as String)
                            else -> Unit
                        }
                    }
                }
```

And here is the code of the `DetailCharacter Composable`:

```
                bottomSheet(
                    route = Screen.DetailCharacterScreen.route,
                    arguments = listOf(
                        navArgument(
                            name = "mal_id"
                        ) {
                            type = NavType.IntType
                        }
                    )
                ) { navBackstack ->
                    val configuration: Configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
                    val screenHeight: Dp = configuration.screenHeightDp.dp
                    val oneThirdHeight: Dp = screenHeight / 3

                    val characterID = navBackstack.arguments?.getInt("mal_id") ?: 0
                    val viewModel: DetailCharacterViewModel = hiltViewModel()
                    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit, block = {
                        Timber.d("Fetching Character with MAL ID $characterID")
                        viewModel.fetchDetailCharacter(characterID = characterID)
                    })
                    val characterResource by viewModel.characterResource.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
                    Surface(
                        modifier = Modifier.animateContentSize()
                    ) {
                        when (characterResource) {
                            is Resource.Error -> {}
                            Resource.Loading -> {
                                Box(
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .height(oneThirdHeight)
                                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                                ) {
                                    CircularProgressIndicator()
                                }
                            }

                            Resource.None -> Unit
                            is Resource.Success -> DetailCharacterScreen(
                                characterResource.data as CharacterDetail
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
```

If you need further information about the code, here is the repository for this project [Lelenime](https://github.com/Kamil-Malik/lelenime)